# Fun NatGeo Powershell Script...needs work

Tags: powershell

I have cobbled together the following script:

$page= iwr http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day

```
Foreach ($image in $page.images.src)
{
$filename=$page.images.alt
Invoke-WebRequest $image.images.src -outfile $filename.jpg

}
```

I cannot seem to parse the list to find the real photo of the day and/or even download the link associated with .images.src.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$folder = 'c:\temp\natgeopics'

if (!(Test-Path $folder)) { md $folder | Out-Null }

(iwr http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day).Images.src | ? {$_ -match [regex]::escape('images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos')} | select -f 1 | % {iwr "http:$_" -OutFile $folder\$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd)$(Split-Path $_ -Leaf)}

start $folder
```